# Session management in Azure application

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

link textI developed a simple cloud application with default webrole and implemented the following steps.

1.Created new cloud service application with one default Webrole1
2.       Extracted “ AspProviders.dll” and added as reference to the current Webrole1.
3.       Added to new web form to the existing web role and named it as Login.aspx
4.       The design page of Login.aspx is edit as below
 
    
         
        
    
  
5.       Below line is added in Page Load event of Default.aspx
 Response.Write("Hello, " + Server.HtmlEncode(User.Identity.Name));
6.       Edited web.config with the following changes
.................

```
<!--Below lines are added to avoid error occured related to  Insecure end points connection -->
```

.................
.................
 
      
      
        
        
      
 
................
................

.................

```
  <sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="TableStorageSessionStateProvider">
    <providers>
      <clear />
       <add name="TableStorageSessionStateProvider"
           type="Microsoft.Samples.ServiceHosting.AspProviders.TableStorageSessionStateProvider"  
           applicationName="SampleCloudApp"/>
    </providers>
  </sessionState>

  <!--End-->
```

.................

...............``
..............


  
    
  


7.       Executed the application in local  DevFabric

But I am getting run time error like "Value Cannot be null" and the stack trace is like the following

Let me know the solution for this

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you pasted in the changes you made to web.config or the stack trace, but I don't see them - maybe try again.

Also have you read [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazure/thread/f7519636-c076-41e3-90f9-e5d2676fd0a7) that mentions the same error?

Note also that AspProviders is just sample code - I found it took a bit of tweaking to get it to work the last time I tried to use it and I seem to remember there was a problem with the role provider.  Not sure if that was fixed or if you're using the June 2010 Azure SDK (hint: you should be.)